# Calculate the modulus of a big sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo

I need to calculate

```
 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2 modulo 10234573
```

for `n` up to *2 billions*. I need to use *native C++ libraries*. I can't figure out how to do it, because it seems like a huge number.

Comment: A signed 32-bit integer has a range from minus two billions to plus two billions. So no problem using normal `int` here. [This table of value ranges](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values) might interest you.

Comment: take a look at congruences http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: This is actually quite interesting. Why not research it?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a huge number - it must be less than 10234573, by definition.  Hint: `(a+b) % n` == `((a%n) + (b%n) %n)`, and `x² % n` == `(x%n)² % n`, so you only need to handle numbers up to 10234573².

Answer (score 6):

You can easily proof by *induction* that

```
 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + ... + k**2 + ... + n**2 == n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6
```

http://oeis.org/A000330

The only difficulty is that you have to divide by `6` and since the sum is an integer value, you have to consider `6` cases (per each possible `n mod 6` outcome):

```
int SumOfSquares(int n) {
  int64_t modulo = 10234573;

  int64_t a = n;
  int64_t b = a + 1;     /* even n+1 can exceed the limit; let's change n to a */
  int64_t c = 2 * a + 1; /* 2*n can exceed the limit; let's change n to a */

  switch (n % 6) {
    case 0:
      a /= 6;
      break;
    case 1:
      b /= 2;
      c /= 3;
      break;
    case 2:
      a /= 2;
      b /= 3;
      break;
    case 3:
      a /= 3;
      b /= 2;
      break;
    case 4:
      a /= 2;
      c /= 3;
      break;
    case 5:
      b /= 6;
      break;
  }

  /* combersome to ensure we are in [0..modulo ** 2] range */
  return (int) (((((a % modulo) * (b % modulo)) % modulo) * (c % modulo)) % modulo);
}
```

It's possible that we'll have a factor up to `(modulo - 1) ** 2 == 104746484492329` and since this exceeds maximum possible 32-bit integer value (`2147483647`) we have to use `int64_t` for the factors.

```
int result = SumOfSquares(2000000000); /* result == 986488 */
```